# [TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace']

Tags: node.js

First off all. I'm not posting questions about the error reason. This suddenly appeared when running an node.js app where after executing the query this error was received. I just want to know how to find the line in the source code where this error appears. How to set node to display extended info in errors like this?

So the error would be displayed like:

```
[TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'] Test.js 123:98
```

Comment: No. That's an example what i want to be displayed. The error that is currently displaying looks like the title. So without the line number.

Comment: if you have a nodejs debugger then you can add a breakpoint for any exception generated but ofcourse this is just for local environment

Answer (score -1):

put line 123 in try and catch the error

```
try{
   // line 123
} catch(e){
   throw e;
}
```

so it will print the stack of the error

Comment: OP said that line 123 is just an example, exact line is not being printed in logs